# insert into database automatically creating a  folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I was just wondering if this is possible. I have a site that admins use to add products to our database. The database is in SQL Server 2008 and I use Visual Studio 2010 using VB.net and was hoping that upon addition of a new product, it would automatically generate a folder assigned to that product's ID.

I haven't found anything online that would suggest that this is a possibility, but it would make it a lot easier for me. As of right now, I have to remember to create a folder in the X: drive for each product that has been added. We are up to 645 products now, so you can see my need for some kind of automation here.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this need to be run purely from the context of that database or can you run a service that checks for new products and creates folders from that?

Comment: I don't really know. If it can be done from a web service that's fine, I just haven't ever heard about something like this. I was hoping someone would tell me that they have done it before and show me how. I have no clue where to start.

Comment: You could make the site create the directory at the time the products are added to the database.  That would allow the database to not "get its hands dirty" creating directories.

Comment: I can just add some code to my vb page on click of the submit button that adds a new product? I'll keep looking for something but I'm not having any luck, if you know how I could do this, I would appreciate sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a web service or web project to create products, you could create the directory there when the user enters a new product.

```
Dim dir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\" & someFolder)
If Not dir.Exists Then 
dir.Create()
End If
```

Comment: Do you know how I could make 'someFolder' be the ID of the current item? I wanted to use IDENT_CURRENT but since its not an sql statement, I don't know I would put it in the statement you wrote.

Comment: Hmm nevermind. I think using the Session("ProductID") will work.

Comment: I used that code with Session("ProductID") and got the error `Could not find a part of the path 'X:\645'.` Any suggestions?

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. If you're running the site as NETWORK SERVICE or some account that doesn't have access to create directories on X:\, that might be the problem.

Comment: Well I can create the folders in Visual Studio just fine. Then when I go into the X drive and create folders in there it works too. Should I just stick to the manual way of doing this? I really would like this to work. But when other users add products, they won't be able to add folders because they won't have access, huh?

Comment: When you create folders, your user is creating folders. When the web service creates folders, it is probably a user local to the machine running the service that is creating the folders.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I looked up the IP address of the X drive and used that instead of X:/ and it gave me the permissions error. It says I need to give permission to the ASP.net request identity.

Answer (score 0):

If products are always added within a call to a stored procedure, you could add code to call xp_cmdshell to "MD < DirName >" after the insertion.  If not done via stored procedures, you could do something similar in an insert trigger. However, both of these are **really bad ideas**. SQL is first and foremost a database engine, not a file system manager or flexible programming tool. You are much better off having the application(s) that cause the creation of products be responsible for manipulating files and folders on your hard drives.

Comment: ...really bad ideas that I've seen people propose doing before. Not a new idea, just one that keeps cropping up.